# Нужно ли делать падежное наращение и как правильно?

Tags: числительные, наращение

"Живет в **12** комнатах" или "в **12-ти** комнатах"?

Comment: Артём, а почему "команатах" оставили без изменения? 

Comment: Наверное, так веселее, и жить в этих "команатах" интереснее...

Comment: Ой, рассмешили))) Не заметил просто, Слава!)

Comment: Правильно жить не запретишь. Ни в 12, ни в 13. Но откуда сама идея-то наращение делать?

Answer (score 4):

Читайте здесь: [Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99?)

> Наращение (буквенное падежное окончание) **используется** в записи **порядковых числительных:** 10-й класс «Б»; ученик 11-го класса; 1-й вагон из центра; 5-й уровень сложности; занять 2-е и 3-е места; в начале 90-х годов, 12-й маршрут.
>
> Наращение ***не используется:***
>
> В записи ***количественных числительных:*** словарь в 4 томах; работа 2 сотрудников; серия из 12 упражнений.

Поэтому правильно: ***"живёт в 12 комнатах"*** или ***"живёт в двенадцати комнатах"***.

Но *"живёт в **12-й** комнат**е**".*